# How to validate a DateTime value?

Tags: c#, validation

I am asking for two dates both have to be in (dd-MM-yyyy) format. I need to let the user only input a valid date like the format and the year has to be 2018 only. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

I tried put them into a while loop something like this.

```
while (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstDate))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Invalid date. Format must be (dd-MM-yyyy)");
            Console.Write("Arrival date: ");
            dateFrom = Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

The problem is I get an error on firstDate and if I change it from int to DateTime then the ParseExact doesn't work and I need the simple date format.

```
String firstDate; //stores the start date
        String secondDate; //stores the end date

Console.Write("Please enter the first date (dd-MM-yyyy):");
        firstDate= Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Please enter the second date (dd-MM-yyyy):");
        secondDate= Console.ReadLine();

DateTime dateOne = DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

         DateTime dateTwo= DateTime.ParseExact(secondDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what were your input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason on why ParseExact could fail is when the Day/Month is single digit. So it is better you try

```
DateTime dateOne = DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "d-M-yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This would ensure it accepts single and double digits for day and month

You can then check if the year is 2018 with DateTime.Year Property

```
dateOne.Year
```

Update

Based on your comment, to check if valid date.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(firstDate, "d-M-yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out var dateOne))
{
Console.WriteLine("Not Valid Format");
}
```

You can also check if the year is 2018 in the same statement.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(firstDate, "d-M-yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out var dateOne) || (dateOne.Year != 2018))
{
Console.WriteLine("Not Valid Format");
}
```

Comment: but let's say the user tries to input a word or an invalid date I want the program to ask him to input a correct date

Comment: You can use DateTime.TryParseExact.

Comment: I have updated answer with example of DateTime.TryParseExact. Kindly check if this is how you like it to be.

Comment: Thanks I will check it in around an hour and update you. Thanks alot for the input

Comment: hey I'm getting errors on CultureInfo and DateTimeStyles (they don't exist in current context

Comment: You need to add reference to System.Globalization namespace

Answer (score 0):

I think you are parsing date correctly, you just need some code to ask it n number of time unless user enters correct date.

```
DateTime firstDate;
bool dateConverted= false;

do{
   var dateString = Console.ReadLine();
   dateConverted= DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString , "dd-MM-YYYY", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out firstDate);

   if(!dateConverted)
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid date");
}
while(!dateConverted)
```

Comment: I'll try this soon. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

When getting input from the user in a `Console` application, I create a library of methods that take a `promp` string (to present to the user), and then validate the results in a loop. This makes it much easier to get data from the user that must be a specific type, and/or must be in a specific range of values, ect.

In this case, we need to get a `DateTime` from the user, and it must be in a specific format. To handle this, I would create the following methods:

```
private static DateTime GetDateWithFormatFromUser(string prompt, 
    List<string> validFormats = null)
{
    // If the user doesn't pass any valid formats, then use a generic method to get the value
    if (validFormats == null || validFormats.Count == 0) return GetDateFromUser(prompt);

    DateTime result;

    // Prompt the user in a loop, where the condition is
    // that the value they enter is in one of our formats.
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), validFormats.ToArray(),
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result));

    return result;
}

private static DateTime GetDateFromUser(string prompt)
{
    DateTime result;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

    return result;
}
```

Now, in our main code, we can create a list of formats that we'll accept (perhaps we will allow one-digit AND two-digit days and months) and then pass it to our validation method above along with the prompt:

```
static void Main()
{
    var validFormats = new List<string>
    {
        "dd-MM-yyyy", "d-MM-yyyy", "dd-M-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy"
    };

    DateTime firstDate = GetDateWithFormatFromUser(
        "Please enter the first date (dd-MM-yyyy): ", validFormats);

    DateTime secondDate = GetDateWithFormatFromUser(
        "Please enter the first date (dd-MM-yyyy): ", validFormats);

    GetKeyFromUser("Done! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: Seems quite complicated, i'll try it out thanks for input

Comment: Not too complicated...it's basically just a `do` loop, where the condition uses `DateTime.TryParseExact` to validate the input using the specified format strings.